# Extracting Number from Line in Log File

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to convert a log file from:

```
2/20/2016 12:23:35 PM 80.0
2/20/2016 12:23:36 PM 76.7
2/20/2016 12:23:37 PM 75.0
2/20/2016 12:23:38 PM 75.4
```

To output only:

```
80.0
76.7
75.0
75.4
```

I have a pre-existing regex but it looks for the number with an A after and won't work for these logs. I know there is an EOL find by number but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
$regex = '/\d+$/'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\d+\.\d+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sS3eL1/1)

Output:

```
80.0
76.7
75.0
75.4
```

Comment: This works perfectly! It actually ignores non-decimal numbers which is great for preventing errors. Thanks Tim!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?:AM|PM) ([0-9.]+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oI1eS7/4):

Input:

```
2/20/2016 12:23:35 AM 80.0
2/20/2016 12:23:36 PM 76.7
2/20/2016 12:23:37 PM 75.0
2/20/2016 12:23:38 PM 75.4
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [22-26] `80.0`
MATCH 2
1.  [49-53] `76.7`
MATCH 3
1.  [76-80] `75.0`
MATCH 4
1.  [103-107]   `75.4`
```